# Function inside map is being called more times than it should React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, map-function

I am mapping over an array of objects in react, and am creating a table row each time I do this. I am using a function to get the class name of the table row depending on the value of the object. However, I am running into an error when trying to get the class name, because the function is being called four times each map, when it should only be called twice.

Here is the code:

```
getClassName(choiceNumber) {
    console.log(parseInt(choiceNumber) === 0); // This logs false, false, true, true for some reason
}


createTable(){
    const table = this.state.results.map(resultObj => {
       return (
               // some code for creating table row, just replaced with header for simplicity
               <h1 className={this.getClassName(choice1)}>First header</h1>
               <h1 className={this.getClassName(choice2)}>Second header</h1>
       
    })
    return table;
}

this.createTable()
```

Does anyone know why this is happening? On top of being called multliple times, when parsing the choice to an integer in the getClassName function, it console.logs `false`, then `false`, then `true` and then `true`

Does anyone know why this is happening? Thanks!

EDIT: In my index.js, my app component is **not** wrapped in `strict mode` tags

Comment: In the current state with, let's say `3` items in your `this.state.results` array, you would generate 6 headers. Is that correct?

Comment: Where does `choice1`, `choice2`, etc. get defined? And what are their values?

Comment: Is `this.createTable()` executed in the `render` method?

Comment: @EmielZuurbier yes, i would generate 6 headers for 3 elements in the array. Choice 1, choice 2, and choice 3 are all defined in the createTable method, in each iteration of the map. And the create table method is called in the render function.

Comment: Please put a `console.log(this.state.results)` in the `createTable` method as well